# Selenium webdriver - driver.Navigate on same page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am doing some testings, with .net Webdriver.

The first test, it opens a windows ok, and for the next steps, what I want is using the same (current web page), and not opening a new window browser each time.

My code is driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/TableauBord");
everytime, i need the tests of my suite to get back to this link, but it open me new window, and my test fail.

I found some codes with driver.to()...but my compiler doesn' t propose this choice.

Can you help me out

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could check the system properties for a possible solution e.g.

```
System.setProperty("restart.browser.each.scenario", "false");
```

might already help you. Otherwise you could try to get all properties by using

`System.getProperties().toString()`

and check if there is a property which fits your need (or maybe you find a list will all properties via Google).

Comment: Hi, I think that your code is using Java,  i am using C#, is there an équivalent in dotnet. thanks

Comment: You could try `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String)` so in your case `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("restart.browser.each.scenario", "false")`

Answer (score 0):

I know its been asked ages ago, but it might be still useful as it was for me.
All you need to do to avoid opening a new browser is wrap your new WebDriver in an if statement.

```
if(WebDriver == null) 
{
    WebDriver = GetChromeDriver(); 
}
else{//the rest of your code}
```